# Fractional Zoom on GMap .net Control

Tags: c#, .net, zooming

As of the most recent source code for the greatmaps project (edited 6/12/16), the ability to perform fractional zooming is still non-working as stated in the ScaleModes enumeration:

```
    public enum ScaleModes
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// no scaling
        /// </summary>
        Integer,

#if !PocketPC
        /// <summary>
        /// scales to fractional level, CURRENT VERSION DOESN'T HANDLE OBJECT POSITIONS CORRECLTY, 
        /// http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/workitem/16046
        /// </summary>
        Fractional,
#endif
    }
```

Fractional zooming is a rather important feature for my project so I will be attempting to get it working properly. Before taking the time, I wanted to see if anyone else has resolved it and if so, how?